# Javascript: Passing Value of Tag to a Variable

Tags: javascript, html

Hope you can help me find a solution to this issue.  I have a page with a number of anchor tags that contain an ID with a unique element.  Here's a sample of the links:

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_1" 
   onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Button</a>

<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_2" 
   onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Button</a>

<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_3" 
   onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Button</a>
```

Below is the code that I tried to create to do collect the values in "id":

```
var num = [];
for (var i = 0; i<11; i++) {
  num[i] = document.getElementsByTagName("id")[i].textContent;
    if (num[i] == "widget_1"){ var y = "39.00"; return y;}
    else if (num[i] == "widget_2"){ var y = "59.00"; return y;}
    else if (num[i] == "widget_3"){ var y = "85.00"; return y;}
    else { var y = "0";}

 return y; }
```

What I'm trying to do is capture what's on id and use it to pass it to the array and if the contents match, then return the value of "y".  For example, if I click on the second link, then 59.00 is returned.  Any help that can be provided will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Ridder

Comment: are you mixing jQuery with pure js?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the value in "id" passed through the for loop. The jQuery in the onclick is how it was setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Another Approach

This approach also allows you to remove the onclick events in markup and improve readability, [separating behavior from structure](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/separating_behavior_and_structure_2/). (aka [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns))

```js
// put your prices on an array;
var prices = [39.0, 59.0, 85.0];

// match all widget(s) (aka anchors), add click handler.
$("[id^=widget]").click(function(element) {
   // calculate the index into prices array based on anchor id.
   var index = parseInt(this.id.substring(7)) - 1;

   // get the pirce
   var price = prices[index];
    
   alert("Price is: " + price);

   // here you could call 
   // this.$parent.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_1">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_2">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_3">Button</a>
```

### Pure Javascript

This version without jQuert. Enjoy!

*Note: There are some limitations on [old browsers (IE < 8 && FF3.0)](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#gettingelements)*

```js
// put your prices on an array;
var prices = [39.0, 59.0, 85.0];

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=widget]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  
  var index = parseInt(element.id.substring(7)) - 1;
  var price = prices[index];
  element.onclick = function(event) {
       alert(price);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_1">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_2">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_3">Button</a>
```

### Extract just the number

```js
var r = /\d+/;
var s = "add_to_cart_sku_ThisItemA1_CEB";
var index = s.match(r);
alert (index);
```

### Extract a substring (for instance "ItemA1")

```js
var code = "add_to_cart_sku_ThisItemA1_CEB";
var strIndex = code.substring(code.indexOf("Item"), code.lastIndexOf('_'));
alert (strIndex);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. One more thing: What does the 7 in the substring means? I went and change widget for the actual element and got undefined.  Here's a sample:  add_to_cart_sku_ThisItemA1_CEB".

Comment: `widget_` have 7 characters length :)

Answer (score 1):

if we can define the function :

```js
function MatchID(id) {
  var y = "0";
  if (id == "widget_1") {
    y = "39.00";
  } else if (id == "widget_2") {
    y = "59.00";
  } else if (id == "widget_3") {
    y = "85.00";
  }
  return y;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button" id="widget_1" onclick="MatchID($(this).attr('id'));$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
switch(document.getElementById(this.id)){
    case "widget_1":
        var value = "59.00";
        break;
    case "widget_2":
        var value = "60.00";
        break;
    case "widget_3":
        var value = "61.00";
        break;
}
return value;
```

that is what you need to get the basic job done, now you just need to get the click to go there, if it is another page you will need to know how it was sent and how it is recieved

hope this helps.

Comment: Any way that I could do this without changing the onclick method? The code for the anchor is set and can't modify it.

Comment: so you can not control the anchor, are you wanting to add a function to the existing page?

Comment: are you looking to store the returned value in an array called num?

Comment: The code is deployed through a dynamic tag management tool, so it's done without modifying the page code.  What I'm looking to return is the value in y, which is the number.  So, if I click the button with widget2, then 59.00 is returned.

Comment: i updated the code to show you the basic things you need to get the information you are trying to get. how is the information sent POST, GET, AJAX?

Comment: so when you click the <a>, you want to send the information that is contained in it to another page via the $GET method, like it is part of a form, and if so that information will not be returned to the page where the <a> is at. Other than that you would have to add the function to the page with the <a>.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` should be given html tag name instead of id and than you can access its `id` attribute as `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].id`
your code should be as follow :

```
var num = [];
for (var i = 0; i<11; i++) {
num[i] = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].id;
if (num[i] == "widget_1"){ var y = "39.00"; return y;}
else if (num[i] == "widget_2"){ var y = "59.00"; return y;}
else if (num[i] == "widget_3"){ var y = "85.00"; return y;}
else { var y = "0";}
return y; }
```

Comment: I made the changes that you recommended, but for some reason it's not working.  Something that I tried is change num[i] for a variable x and although it works, it passes all three values.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("id")` this line in your code is not correct because there's no tags in html that is called `.

To retrieve all of the `<a>` tags in your document, there's a property of the `HTMLDocument` interface which is referred to as the `document` object which represents the entire html document. To retrieve all of the `<a>` tags. use this.

`document.links` this method returns a collection of the `<a>` tags, you can access this collection just like you do an array. For example, to access the first child in that collection.

`document.links[0].href` to get its href value or to get its id, you do `document.links[0].id` . Hope this helps